# How to plot with x = column A, but color/hue = column B categorical vars

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to create a bar plot from using Seaborn. The problem is  I want to use one of two categorical variables, say column A, in X-axis, but a different categorical column, say column B, to color the bars. Values in B can represent more than one value in A.

```
        MajorCategories               name                 review_count    
Food,Restaurants              Mon Ami Gabi                  8348
Food,Restaurants              Bacchanal Buffet              8339
Restaurants                   Wicked Spoon                  6708
Food,Restaurants              Hash House A Go Go            5763
Restaurants                   Gordon Ramsay BurGR           5484
Restaurants                   Secret Pizza                  4286
Restaurants                   The Buffet at Bellagio        4227
Hotels & Travel              McCarran International Airport 3627
Restaurants                  Yardbird Southern Table & Bar  3576
```

So, I would like my barplot to plot the bars with x = 'name' and y='review_count', at the same time color/hue?? = Major Categories. It is possible in Seaborn without many lines of code?

Below are the links to the images I get in seaborn, and the one I am trying to get.

```
sns.catplot(x="review_count", y="name", kind="bar", data=plot_data,  aspect= 1.5)
```

Plot I get using seaborn using the code above

[image: Plot I get using seaborn using the code above]

Plot I am trying to achieve, this one is using ggplot2 in R
[image: Plot I am trying to achieve, this one is using ggplot2 in R]

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `hue` and set `dodge=False`:

```
sns.catplot(x="review_count", y="name", hue='MajorCategories',
            kind="bar", data=plot_data,
            dodge=False, aspect= 1.5)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: wow, didn't know it was that simple- thank you! I surely missed it in the seaborn barplot documentation.